# Advices to Manage Academic Department

Tags: management

I am a new faculty who happen to be chairing a department of 25 professors. Are there any standards/procedures I should follow to organize the work in our (computer science) department? scheduling, teaching loads, accreditations, QA, graduate projects,..etc are all duties need to be carried on sometimes in term basis.

Comment: All I can say is you got screwed. Universities should not allow departments to make new faculty (even if they are new with tenure) to be chair. That is just not fair.

Comment: @StrongBad Unless they were explicitly searching for a department chair, which does happen.

Comment: Hire a really really really good administrative assistant who is experienced in all university procedures. And start relationships with chairs of related departments who you can ask questions. Copy everything possible from them (forms/procedures/timelines).

Comment: @Dawn Please consider converting your comment into an answer.